# Change UITableViewCell Height based UICollectionView content size height

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, row-height

I'm working on a calendar created with a `UICollectionView`.

The `UICollectionView` is located inside a `UITableViewCell`
The `UITableViewCell` in the `heightForRowAt` method `return UITableView.automaticDimension`

The `UICollectionView` used to create the calendar updates its height based on how many days are shown, for example the month of **November** has its **first day which falls on Sunday** so to place the day under the label **"Sunday"** the `collectionView` must necessarily add a whole line.

Normally **each month has 5 rows** (week) but when the **first day of the month** happens on **Sunday** the `collectionview` **returns 6**

Now as I said I was able to update the height of the **UICollectionView** based on how many rows it returns but I cannot dynamically change the **height** of the `TableViewCell` that contains the `collectionView`

How can I resize the `tableViewCell` based on the height of the `CollectionView` within it?

---

**EDIT**

**my cell**

[image]

---

I have set `UITableView.automaticDimension` for the height of the cell that contains the `CalendarView`

### [image]

In the class `CalendarView: UIView` I created a variable CGFloat calendarH to set the default height of the collectionView

[image]

**CollectionView implementation**

[image]

I have added an observer which tracks the height of the `collctionView` when it changes

[image]

I am currently able to change the height of the `collectionView` but its superview (`bookingCalendarView`) and the tableView cell continue to remain with a fixed height and do not adapt to the `collectionView`

Comment: How are you setting the height of your collection view?

Comment: @DonMag i didn't set a fixed height .. i put the top, leading, trailing and bottomAnchor on the cell

Comment: OK - a collection view has no intrinsic height. If you know your row height is, say, 20... and you have 5 rows, the collection view needs a height constraint of 100 (plus spacing if you have it)... if you have 6 rows, the collection view needs a height constraint of 120 (plus spacing if you have it).

Comment: @DonMag I have a collectionView with 6 cells (I have entered the highest height that the collectionView reaches .. when for example the first day of the week happens on Sunday). The height is 450 (75 (cell) x 6 rows) but when the collectionView changes the number of rows the tableviewcell does not update its size..I added a photo of the xib to show you the constraints I entered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an `@IBOutlet` for your collection view's height constraint.

When you set a row's calendar / month data, determine whether you need 5 or 6 rows.

If it's 6, set the `.constant` on the height constraint to `750`

If it's 5, set the `.constant` on the height constraint to `675`

---

**Edit**

First, I'm going to suggest you forget about using a "self-sizing" collection view. `UICollectionView` is designed to lay out cells *based on the size of the collection view*, providing automatic scrolling when there are too many cells.

Trying to "self-size" it ***may*** work in one instance, but fail in another. The reason it fails in this case is because your table view lays out the cell and calculates its height ***before*** the collection view is populated, and thus before it can "self-size."

Instead, since you know your cell Height is 75, you can calculate how many rows your calendar will need and either set the `.constant` on a height constraint for your collection view, or (since you're already using `heightForRowAt`) calculate the row height there.

Look at this code:

```
let dateComponents = DateComponents(year: year, month: month)
        
// startDate will be the first date of the month (Jan 1, Feb 1, Mar 1, etc...)
guard let startDate = calendar.date(from: dateComponents) else {
    fatalError("Something is wrong with the date!")
}
// get the range of days in the month
guard let range = calendar.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: startDate) else {
    fatalError("Something is wrong with the date!")
}
        
// get number of days in the month
let numberOfDaysInMonth = range.count
        
// get the day of the week for the first date in the month
//  this returns 1-based numbering
//  Nov 1, 2020 was a Sunday, so this would return 1
let startDayOfWeek = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: startDate)
        
// add the "leading days to the start date"
//  so, if startDayOfWeek == 3 (Tuesday)
//  we need to add 2 "empty day cells" for Sunday and Monday
let totalCellsNeeded = numberOfDaysInMonth + (startDayOfWeek - 1)
        
// calculate number of rows needed -- this will be 4, 5 or 6
//  the only time we get 4 is if Feb 1st in a non-leapYear falls on a Sunday
let numRows = Int(ceil(Double(totalCellsNeeded) / Double(7)))
        
// we now know the Height needed for the collection view
//  you said your calendar cell height is 75, so...
//  cvHeight = numRows * 75
```

We can put that in a loop and `print()` the information to the debug console like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    // 2026 is the next year where Feb starts on a Sunday
    //  so let's use that year to see that we get 4 rows for Feb
    let year = 2026
    
    for month in 1...12 {
        
        let dateComponents = DateComponents(year: year, month: month)
        
        // startDate will be the first date of the month (Jan 1, Feb 1, Mar 1, etc...)
        guard let startDate = calendar.date(from: dateComponents) else {
            fatalError("Something is wrong with the date!")
        }
        // get the range of days in the month
        guard let range = calendar.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: startDate) else {
            fatalError("Something is wrong with the date!")
        }
        
        // get number of days in the month
        let numberOfDaysInMonth = range.count
        
        // get the day of the week for the first date in the month
        //  this returns 1-based numbering
        //  Nov 1, 2020 was a Sunday, so this would return 1
        let startDayOfWeek = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: startDate)
        
        // add the "leading days to the start date"
        //  so, if startDayOfWeek == 3 (Tuesday)
        //  we need to add 2 "empty day cells" for Sunday and Monday
        let totalCellsNeeded = numberOfDaysInMonth + (startDayOfWeek - 1)
        
        // calculate number of rows needed -- this will be 4, 5 or 6
        //  the only time we get 4 is if Feb 1st in a non-leapYear falls on a Sunday
        let numRows = Int(ceil(Double(totalCellsNeeded) / Double(7)))
        
        // we now know the Height needed for the collection view
        //  you said your calendar cell height is 75, so...
        //  cvHeight = numRows * 75
        
        // debug output
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
        let dayName = dateFormatter.string(from: startDate)
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "LLLL y"
        let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: startDate)
        
        let dayPadded = dayName.padding(toLength: 10, withPad: " ", startingAt: 0)
        let datePadded = dateString.padding(toLength: 16, withPad: " ", startingAt: 0)

        print("\(datePadded) has \(numberOfDaysInMonth) days, starting on \(dayPadded) requiring \(numRows) rows")
        
    }
    
}
```

Here's the output:

```
January 2026     has 31 days, starting on Thursday   requiring 5 rows
February 2026    has 28 days, starting on Sunday     requiring 4 rows
March 2026       has 31 days, starting on Sunday     requiring 5 rows
April 2026       has 30 days, starting on Wednesday  requiring 5 rows
May 2026         has 31 days, starting on Friday     requiring 6 rows
June 2026        has 30 days, starting on Monday     requiring 5 rows
July 2026        has 31 days, starting on Wednesday  requiring 5 rows
August 2026      has 31 days, starting on Saturday   requiring 6 rows
September 2026   has 30 days, starting on Tuesday    requiring 5 rows
October 2026     has 31 days, starting on Thursday   requiring 5 rows
November 2026    has 30 days, starting on Sunday     requiring 5 rows
December 2026    has 31 days, starting on Tuesday    requiring 5 rows
```

So... either in:

- `cellForRowAt` ... calculate the needed height and set the CV height in the cell, or
- `heightForRowAt` ... calculate and return the needed height for the row

Side note: I'd suggest using auto-layout for all of your cells, instead of returning various row heights.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224884/discussion-on-answer-by-donmag-change-uitableviewcell-height-based-uicollectionv).